# can't show caret icon for sorting beside the column name

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I can't show caret icon for sorting beside the column name using react-bootstrap-table2 even i set the attribut sort to true in columns.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this link will solve your problem https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/215

Answer (score 2):

If, by default, the caret is missing, you may add the following styles to your global stylesheet.

```
.caret {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: 4px dashed;
    border-top: 4px solid \9;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```